# Handling references in breezejs

Tags: json, reference, knockout.js, breeze

We are developing a single page app using ASP.NET MVC4 with Web Api + Ko + Breeze using EF Code First.

Our (simplified) data model looks like this

```
class Product {
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ImageCollection> ImageSets { get; set;}
    public Image DefaultImage { get; set; }
}

class ImageCollection {
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

class Image {
    public String ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

DefaultImage is a navigation property (with foreign key) and is one of the images in the ImageSets.

We are exposing a Web API method of Products() and with default Breeze configuration. JSON serialized output on the wire has references for objects (i.e., PreserveReferencesHandling.Object) so when I want to bind the ImageUrl ko is unable to resolve the value.

Html looks like this

```
 <img data-bind="attr: { src: DefaultImage().ImageUrl, title: Name}" />
```

When I switch the serializer to do PreserveReferencesHandling.None, the binding works.

Question: how do I make the default config to work? or if I switch to PreserveReferencesHandling.None for Breeze what are the gotchas/downsides?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your model? It may be too simplified for me. If `DefaultImage` and `ImageSets` are nav properties, what are the foreign keys? None of the classes have keys. Are there image tables to go with the `Image` type? I'm struggling to understand how the `ImageCollection` type is a Code First type and how `ImageSets` works in EF as an `ICollection` of an `ICollection`.

Also don't know why you're setting JSON serialization options; is there something wrong with using the Breeze.WebApi.JsonFormatterAttribute as shown for all Breeze sample controllers?

Comment: Sorry for not having responded or updated on this. Yead, I may have over simplified the ImageCollection, there are bunch of other "data properties" on it with a Primary Key. We have since found out why it wasn't working. After reading the documentation more carefully, we realised Breeze only supports association with explicit Foreign Key specification in models and we were using Independent Associations. Why is this limitation in place?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you do NOT  want to switch PreserveReferencesHandling to None because you will lose the ability to serialize circular references and your payloads will get much larger.

I don't actually understand why your binding would begin to work after setting this. The first step to understanding this is probably to check that the ko objects actually contain the correct data after your query.

Remember that breeze navigation properties are lazy-loaded, so you may not have loaded them with your initial query.  Take a look at the "EntityAspect.loadNavigationProperty" method.